# Menú Fijo o adhesivo no me funciona

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, menú

Un gran saludo, ya he realizado el menú es un menú hamburguesa, con un header o un texto a un lado, en general el problema que tengo es que no me queda fijo o adhesivo ( a pesar de que se le haga scroll, se conserve el menú en la parte superior), ya probé con position:fixed, y no funcionana.

Nota: Estoy usando el frame de Bootstrap

No se cual sera el problema, he subrayado el menú, GRACIAS.
[image: Menú]

```js
<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("sideNavigation").style.width = "250px";
    //*document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
 
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sideNavigation").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
</script>
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}
 
/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}
 
/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #FF0D86;
}
 
/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
 
/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
   
}
 /*opacity: 0.0;*/
/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #00A2FF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
 
/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #FF0D86;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/favicom.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <!--Javascript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min"></script>
</head>    

<body>
    
<div id="sideNavigation" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="index.html">Inicio</a>
  <a href="nosotros.html">Nosotros</a>
  <a href="servicios.php">Servicios</a>
  <a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
</div>
 
<nav class="topnav">
  <a href="#" onclick="openNav()"> 
    <svg width="30" height="30" id="icoOpen">
        <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"/>
        <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"/>
        <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"/>
    </svg>
  </a>
<h1><b>MOLDEAR</b> LAS IDEAS</h1>
</nav>



<div id="main">
 ...
</div>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es la posición fixed, desde Bootstrap puedes crearlo con una clase, pero ya que personalizaste tu css solo agrega esto:

```
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;    
    margin-top: 65px;
  }

.topnav {
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    top: 0;
  }
```

También en el Head, llamas en orden incorrecto las librerías de JS, eso te puede dar problema más adelante.
JQuery tiene que ir antes del bootstrap.bundle

Espero te ayude

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha sido de utilidad  tu apoyo, a funcionado, gracias.

Comment: Excelente! Que gusto saberlo